# JQuery how to .Load() html file with local image links/filepaths?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an index.html page in my root folder and I want to load into a div a HTM file which is located in a sub-folder with a javascript jQuery.load() function. That htm file has image references in it to images in it's own folder, so when I load it into the div, the image links break and no image shows.

so e.g: if my root folder is called "root", then the htm file I am loading into the div is located in: "root\firstfolder". and am doing it with the following code:

```
loadButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    $("loadDivID").load("root\firstfolder\page1");
});
```

that htm file has a line like follows:

```
<img width=517 height=387 id="_x0000_i1025"
src="COMPLETE_files/image001.jpg"
```

however this image breaks when loaded into the div and displayed in the index page. I am assuming this is because the link to the image here is a local file path and after loading obviously it breaks.

What is the best way to achieve this without breaking the image links? Ideally with JQuery or regular javascript/HTML and keeping the local file-paths.

Thanks.

Comment: It would help us help you if you could include the code that you have tried so far. See [ask] to learn more about what is required from questions here.

Comment: Added more clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Firstly you are using the wrong terminology. Your image is not "local", the url to image is a "relative" path. Local generally means the file is only in your computer and can be accessed via "file://...". This is a known/common issue when injecting html from one file into another file using .load(). Use full path in your html relative to root. For example: src="./root/firstfolder/COMPLETE_files/image001.jpg"

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using full paths? or do I have to manually edit them all?